Light up (green) on / off (red) 12V switch for a ground completing circuit
Is there a light up 12 V (green) on / off (red) switch for a ground completing circuit?
I am trying to wire up a converter lock up switch on my 2005 Dodge Ram 2500 transmission (48RE).
In order to do this, you have to splice into the TC (torque converter) control wire at the transmission and run a wire to a 33 ohm resistor then to a switch and from the switch to a ground.
Most people use a 2 post toggle switch, but I was curious if there is a way to have a light up switch. I found one for a regular 12 V circuit green when on and red when off, but this is a ground completing circuit, not a live circuit

Please confirm if you have access to 12V power to bring to the location of the LED?  And would turning on a single LED (color doesn't matter) on when the switch is engaged to ground the signal (lock the torque converter) be acceptable (with no LED lit when switch is off)?  More difficult to have two different colors for on/off.  Do you want the LED built-into the switch or are you willing to mount it separately?

use a DPDT switch ... use one side for the converter and the other side for the LEDs
